# Fill columns using indices

Tags: r, data.table

Given the following data frames:

```
df1 <- data.table("1A"=c(0,0,0,0),"1B"=c(1:4),"2A"=c(0,0,0,0), "2B"=c(1:4))
df2 <- data.table("1A"=c(1:4),"2A"=c(1:4))
> df1
   1A 1B 2A 2B
1:  0  1  0  1
2:  0  2  0  2
3:  0  3  0  3
4:  0  4  0  4
> df2
    1  2
 1: 1  1
 2: 2  2
 3: 3  3
 4: 4  4
```

Targeted columns, which contain the identifier "A", are identified with the following index:

```
indx = grep("A", colnames(df1))
> indx
[1] 1 3
```

I seek to fill the values of the columns identified by 'indx' with those from df2, in the same order and without changing df1 colnames. So that:

```
 > df1
       1A 1B 2A 2B
    1:  1  1  1  1
    2:  2  2  2  2
    3:  3  3  3  3
    4:  4  4  4  4
```

Please note that this a simplified example, my actual data contains about 50 columns that I need to fill, so I need a programatical approach.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is abnormal syntax, but... `df1[,indx] <- df2`

Comment: Thank you @Frank! Works neatly as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by @Frank's comment - same thing works with regular `:=` syntax, and doesn't introduce an extra copy:

```
df1[, (indx) := df2]
```

Comment: When I use this syntax in my real data, the following error appears: "Supplied 460800 items to be assigned to 9600 items of column 'SE ICE cars' (451200 unused) [...] 48 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector", and only the first column is copied over and over. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: sounds like your RHS (i.e. `df2`) is a matrix and not a `data.table` as you presented in OP, so convert to a `data.table` first

Comment: To avoid using `with`, this instead `df1[,(indx):= df2]`

Comment: @PierreLafortune good point, I forgot that also works with column numbers.